# Android Package Name Issue

Tags: android, package-name

if my developer account is terminated then may i use my previous application package name again? 
note: When my developer account terminated, my application is running. Account is terminated due to other app's content policy.

that is i used in my application com.companyname.applicationname  - in which developer account terminated.

I want to use same name again, may i?

Comment: Ask the answer to Harshit Patel he will give you answer or Reserve your account at google so that it can't be terminated ever again...

Answer (score 1):

No - Package-names can only be used once